# jQuery: modificar el estilo CSS de un elemento HTML al interaccionar con el ratón con otro elemento diferente

Tags: jquery, css

Estoy haciendo una página web sobre música con el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cada año hay 15 canciones que se disponen una debajo de la otra repitiendo este mismo patrón (amén de otras cosas que no vienen a cuento, esto sería una `col` del `main`).

Lo que quiero es que al pasar el puntero por encima del vídeo el número cambie de aspecto (he aprobado a agrandarlo, pero quizá sería mejor que oscile o algo así; esto de momento no es importante) y al sacarlo de los límites del iframe, el número vuelva a la normalidad.

El código es el siguiente:

```
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
{
    $enlace_youtube = $fila['enlace_youtube'];
    $titulo_cancion = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_cancion']);
    $nombre_autor = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_autor']);
    $enlace_rym = $fila['enlace_rym'];
    $nombre_ciudad = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_ciudad']);
    $nombre_pais = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_pais']);
    $votos_facebook = $fila['votos_facebook'];
    $tipo = $fila['tipo'];
    $titulo_disco = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_disco']);
    $ano = $fila['ano'];
    $id_cancion = $fila['id_cancion'];

    $inicio = strpos($enlace_youtube, "watch?v=");
    $enlace_youtube = substr_replace($enlace_youtube, "embed/", $inicio, 8);

    if(strpos($nombre_autor, ", The")) $nombre_autor = "The ".substr($nombre_autor, 0, strpos($nombre_autor, ", The"));

    $decada = substr($ano, 0, 3)."0s";

    if(strpos($titulo_disco, "/")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, "/"));
    elseif(strpos($titulo_disco, ":")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, ":"));
    else $nombre_foto = $titulo_disco;

    if($condicion == true) $ano_disco = '('.$ano.')';
    else $ano_disco = null;

    $count++;

    echo '<div class ="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"><iframe id="video" width="575" height="323.5" src='.$enlace_youtube.' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'; #Vídeo

    ?>

    <div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación -->

        <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2"> <!-- Portada -->
            <?php echo '<img id="portada" src="imagenes/'.$decada.'/'.$ano.'/'.$nombre_foto.'.jpg" width="150" height="150">'; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col"> <!-- Información y sistema de votación -->

            <div class="row"> <!-- Información (con clasificación) -->

                <div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span id="numero">'.$count.'</span>'; ?> </div> <!-- Clasificación -->

                <div class="col informacion"> <!-- Información -->
                    <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos"><span class="titulos">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span> de&nbsp<span><a id="autor" href="'.$enlace_rym.'" target="_blank">'.$nombre_autor.'</a></span></div>'; ?></div>
                    <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">('.$nombre_ciudad.', '.$nombre_pais.')</div>'; ?></div>
                    <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">Incluida en su '.$tipo.'&nbsp<span class="titulos">'.$titulo_disco.'</span>&nbsp'.$ano_disco.'</div>'; ?></div>
                    <div class="row "><?php echo '<span id="votos">'.$votos_facebook.'&nbsp</span>'; if($votos_facebook == 1) echo 'voto'; else echo 'votos'; ?></div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row"> <!-- Sistema de votación -->

                <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

                    <?php if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"><i></i>'; ?>

                </span>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function()
        {
            $('#video').mouseover(function()
            {
                $('#numero').css("font-size", "62.5px");
            });

            $('#video').mouseout(function()
            {
                $('#numero').css("font-size", "50px");
            });
        });

    </script>

    <?php
}
```

Esto procede de una llamada a la base de datos, de manera que mediante el bucle while vaya presentando toda la información pertinente para cada canción, una detrás de otra.

Lo relevante es el vídeo:

```
echo '<div class ="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"><iframe id="video" width="575" height="323.5" src='.$enlace_youtube.' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
```

El número:

```
<div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span id="numero">'.$count.'</span>'; ?> </div>
```

Con su estilo CSS:

```
#numero {
    color: mediumvioletred;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px pink;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

Y el script de jQuery (es uno de mis primeros intentos con JS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('#video').mouseover(function()
        {
            $('#numero').css("font-size", "62.5px");
        });

        $('#video').mouseout(function()
        {
            $('#numero').css("font-size", "50px");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Bien, el asunto es que no he podido usar `addClass()` porque entonces no ocurre nada (supongo que porque el número tiene un `id` y no una `class`), así que por comprobar que no era un fallo básico de sintaxis de jQuery le metí `css()` y hay cierta reacción, pero limitada: en función de que se le asigne `id` o `class` a los dos elementos que nos ocupan, el vídeo y el número, el comportamiento es diferente pero en ningún caso satisfactorio; tal y como esta ahora, al pasar el puntero por el vídeo el número se agranda y al retirarlo se empequeñece, pero sólo ocurre para el primer vídeo, en los 14 restantes no hay reacción; si en vez de `id="video"` pongo `class="video"` entonces (creo, hablo de memoria a partir de pruebas que hice ayer) sigue reaccionando sólo el primer número pero al pasar el ratón por cualquiera de los vídeos, y así sucesivamente probando las cuatro diferentes combinaciones.

Resumiendo: cómo hago para que cada número reaccione si y sólo si se interacciona con su vídeo. Intuyo que he de relacionar de alguna forma cada vídeo y cada número, como hice con el radiobotón, asignándole el `id_cancion` que procede de la BD:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"><i></i>'; ?>
```

Qué tochaco me ha quedado. Gracias ya sólo por leer hasta aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El atributo `id` debe ser único, por eso, cuando usas en la función de **Jquery** el selector `('#video')` está aplicándolo solamente al primero (hay que evitar tener elementos con `id` dentro de bucles, ya que esto ocasionará que múltiples elementos tengan la misma `id`. En caso de ser necesario que la tengan, se suele usar una `id` autoincremental para que no sea la misma exactamente). Yo le quitaría la `id` al vídeo y lo cambiaría por una clase, que se trata de un atributo que si que se puede repetir a lo largo de nuestra página. Lo mismo ocurre con tu `<span>`, se le debería cambiar `id="numero"` por `class="numero"`.

Pero entonces tendríamos un nuevo problema: **¿Cómo detectamos qué vídeo es al que se le hace `mouseenter/mouseleave`?** Pues por medio del selector `this`, que en nuestro caso va a hacer referencia al elemento que dispara el evento. Tu **Javascript** quedaría así:

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('.contenedor-youtube').mouseenter(function()
        {
            $(this).next().find('.numero').css("font-size", "62.5px");
        });

        $('.contenedor-youtube').mouseleave(function()
        {
            $(this).next().find('.numero').css("font-size", "50px");
        });
    });

</script>
```

De esta manera el `this` hace referencia al elemento `.contenedor-youtube` en el que el ratón entra/sale, con `next()` buscamos su elemento hermano inmediatamente posterior en el **DOM** (en nuestro caso es `div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación -->`) y con `find()` buscamos el hijo de ese elemento que tenga la clase `.numero` y a ese es al que le aplicamos el cambio de estilo.

Answer (score 2):

Te funciona con el id por ser mas *específico*, pero tanto que sólo funciona con el primero. No necesitas complicarte con JS, con la pseudo-clase **hover** y el selector **adjacent-sibling** en css lo puedes conseguir:

```
.contenedor-youtube:hover + .portada .ranking{ font-size: 62.5px; }
```

```css
.contenedor-youtube{background: darkgrey; height:100px;}
.contenedor-portada{background: #eee; height: 100px; width: 30%;}
.ranking{font-size: 50px;}
.contenedor-youtube:hover + .portada .ranking{ font-size: 62px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"></div>
<div class="row portada">
  <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ranking mr-3">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```